# Got stuck while designing inheritance, Which one is correct?

Tags: java, inheritance, coding-style, uml

Trying to write a trivial application, But I have stuck into one of the inheritance problem,

Which one of these is correct? specifically which one should be correct based on particular scenario?

A).

[image]

**OR**

B).

[image]

Thanks for any input given.

Comment: It depends whether you're trying to say "a programmer is a developer" or vice versa.

Comment: Why close? This is a programming related question :)

Comment: both of them implements nerd interface :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a square a rectangle? Yes, mathematically! Should a square class inherit from a rectangle class? [Definitely not (pdf)!](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf)

Is a developer a programmer? Since this is much harder to answer than the question above, I'd prefer not to model this relationship with inheritance. They could be siblings, and share a common abstract class or interface.

But if you can provide more information, like behaviors, responsibilities and scenarios, that would help finding the right design.

**UPDATE**:

Every design should serve a *purpose*. If you don't have an application to build, with *requirements* to fulfill, design for the sake of design is a futile exercise in frustration.

Comment: Normally by definition programmers are the one who write something from scratch and developers are the one who develops an application later on! Or vice verca I guess i should use them as siblings as it seems like a controvercial topic :(

Comment: Yes, I agree. But it's only controversial because there's too little information you provided. I've updated my answer with something related to this.

Comment: +1 for mentioning LSP. Saying a Y *is a* X is an intuitive way to introduce the concepts of subclassing and substitution, but after that it's a dead end that we basically have to unlearn before we can start writing flexible, maintainable, and reusable code.

Comment: Thanks bro! that last bit helped a lot ;)

Comment: You had me at "Is a Square a Rectangle"! :-)  Then you got snotty with the whole "Update" bit... :-)

Comment: _"There ain't nothin' in this world that's worth being a snot over."_ -- Larry Wall

Answer (score 1):

Depends--which one inherits from the other?

The arrow should be on (touching, pointing at) the superclass, if your question is how to draw the UML diagram showing inheritance.

If you're asking for a *conceptual* answer, IMO a developer is a subclass of programmer, because developers add behavior. Anyone can program (well...) but not everyone is a developer.

Matter of definition.

Answer (score 1):

LOL.  A Developer "IS A" Programmer so B is correct but I would invert the diagram to put Developer on top of programmer with the "Using" arrow pointing to Programmer. I like to do this to show the "base" relationship--that Programmer is the Base class for developer (though I'm sure this will spark fury in some.

At the same time, this is a philosophical question (as I assume you well know).

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance expresses "is a" relationship.

Is every programmer a developer?

Is every developer a programmer?

Maybe both?

Depends on the domain your application deals with. I.E. real estate developers have little to do with broadcast programmers.

Comment: This draws out a point I forgot to make.  You should prefer a "HAS A" relationship over an "IS A" (aggregation vs. inheritance).  To @DavidSchwartz point, if some Developers are not programmers than it makes it hard to say Developer "IS A" programmer--although I think a Developer *IS A* Programmer in actuality.  If you are trying to represent a software team than I suggest you consider a different class structure.  Avoid the "Developer" moniker as ambiguous and use something like "TeamMember" or "Consultant" or "Pig" (if Scrum is your flavor)--grin.

Answer (score 1):

If you have developers who are not programmers, it's A. If you have programmers who are not developers, it's B. If you have both or neither, it's neither.